# Receiving only chunks of an uploaded file in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm making a simple PHP script which lets the user upload an image. These images are quite large, so I would like to display a progressbar so that the user knows how far the upload has progressed.

It is important for me not to use third party scripts in this case, and pure PHP, HTML and Javascript only (no CGI either, and no client-side technologies such as Silverlight or Flash either).

I have found some documentation regarding file upload in PHP, but only how to handle the final uploaded file once it is uploaded, and not save the file incrementally as it is received, which is needed in my specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP v5.4 and greater has a built-in support for upload progress indication...
Check this out:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PECL extension [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) (PHP >= 5.2.0), in case you don't have PHP 5.4 installed, as suggested in kgb's answer. [This comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#71564) on PHP.net briefly explains its general setup. You can find examples via the extension's PECL page.