# Can I limit upload size in PHP but still receive truncated files?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I would like people to upload any size file to my site but I need only first 1 kB of it. So I would like PHP to somehow stop receiving a file after it got this 1 kB and then just process this truncated file.

Comment: I don't think you can. You can either deny entire files if they are bigger with your configuration, or you can receive entire file and then crop it.

Comment: You can receive the file and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks, but this is not the best solution. If I need 1 kB of file for my script and someone wants to upload 1 GB then this is wasting time and CPU cycles to receive whole file and truncate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this question, Maybe it has the answer for you.

> [Receiving only chunks of an uploaded file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394435/receiving-only-chunks-of-an-uploaded-file-in-php)

Comment: This way I can stop transfer but there is no way to get the transfered data.

Comment: I think you can access the tmp file, before you stop upload.

Comment: Here http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php for the "An other file, not finished uploading" the tmp_name is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

**Version 2**. *If you cant do it with basic php support, then:*

Create a new php, with a tcp socket server. Start the socket on another port, for example 8080, and that will handle your file upload.

You wait for start of the content (trim headers, and other unneeded data.), and when you got 1kb of uploaded file, you can parse it, and maybe send a redirection back to client, and handle that data.
So a little tricky, but not impossible.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks. But the problem is I cannot change HTML upload form and it is a very basic POST form.

Comment: Then you have to write a .htaccess proxy, what passes the entire upload to this solution.